# Methods to create a palindrome

Tags: java, methods, palindrome

So I am terrible at programming, I have to do this for a college course and cannot get my head around some of the concepts.  This is what I have to this point.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I call these methods to return a cohesive message to main?  The check method was borrowed from another site to fill the gap while I try to figure out the stringbuffer method of verifying a palindrome.  A lot of the comments are works inprogress that have not been completed.  If this is too messed up let me know and I will start over.  Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static String retrieveInput(String number) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
        number = input.toString();

        while (number.length() != 5) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!  Integer must be 5 digits. Please enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            number = input.toString();
        }
        if (number.matches("[0-9]+")) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!! Input must be numeric. Please enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            number = input.toString();
        }
        return number;
    } 

    // Change, TESTING ONLY!!!!!!!
    public static String check(String number) {
        String original = number;
        String reverse = "";

        int length = original.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        if (original.equals(reverse))
            System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");

        return number;
        //StringBuffer Palindrome = new StringBuffer(number);
        //return number.equals(reverseString);
    }

    //StringBuffer original = new StringBuffer();
    //  StringBuffer reverse = original.reverse();  
    //  if (original != original.reverse()) {
    //  System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");
    //}
    //return number;

    public static String display(String number) {
        return number + " is a valid palindrome!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the user input by the `Scanner` object? I cannot see any `next()` or `nextLine()` method call in here..

Comment: As @MehmetSedatGüngör mentioned, you're using `input` incorrectly. Use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.toString()`.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Can I ask what the difference is as I have seen both used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (modified with minor changes)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome { // Prefer beginning class name with a capital letter
                          // (Java naming convention)

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static String retrieveInput(String number) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
        number = input.nextLine(); // Replace this

        while (number.length() != 5) {
            System.out
                    .println("ERROR!!!  Integer must be 5 digits. Please enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            number = input.nextLine(); // Replace this
        }
        if (number.matches("[0-9]+")) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!! Input must be numeric. Please enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit integer: ");
            number = input.nextLine(); // Replace this
        }

        input.close(); // Close your scanner after you are done using it.

        return number;
    }

    // Change, TESTING ONLY!!!!!!!
    public static String check(String number) {
        String original = number;
        String reverse = "";

        int length = original.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        if (original.equals(reverse))
            System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");

        return number;
        // StringBuffer Palindrome = new StringBuffer(number);
        // return number.equals(reverseString);
    }

    // StringBuffer original = new StringBuffer();
    // StringBuffer reverse = original.reverse();
    // if (original != original.reverse()) {
    // System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");
    // }
    // return number;

    public static String display(String number) {
        return number + " is a valid palindrome!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this code still doesn't work, I recommend that you remove all the unchanged code lines and keep the changed ones. Also describe why you've changed them.

Comment: I guess people have already explained what needs to be changed. I have just made it easier for him by suggesting where exactly the changes have to made and anyways he is working on it, so he can work on this. Doesn't it makes things easier and simpler?

Comment: Thank you for the hints here.  As I said I have no idea what I am doing, this is going to be a long course I think.  Could anyone explain exactly how methods are called?  I would really like to learn this so that maybe when I have the time I can get better at it.  Cheers!